# Create Folders in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint, I do most of C# but now i wanted to do something with Sharepoint. 
Now I want to create a Folder which I can use for file conversion which has to have an origin as well as a destination (Origin files are Docx and Destination is PDF)  I cannot seem to see where i create the folders from.

I am using Sharepoint 2016, Please How can I go about something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can create Document Library to securely store files

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Document Library, then create a new folder using Ribbon Menu:

[image]